# Shipping Groups Conditional in Stencil Big Commerce

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I'm trying to write a conditional in Big Commerce Stencil so if the Shipping Groups field in the Product configuration area contains 'In Store Pickup Only', 'In Store Pickup Only' displays on the product page.

This store is using ShipperHQ, so I'm not sure if that field is from Big Commerce or part of ShipperHQ. I'm having a hard time trying to find any guidance in helper docs.

Using Handlebars.js, I was trying to do something like:

```
{{#if product.shipping_groups.value '===' "In Store Pickup Only"}}
    <p><strong>In store pickup only</strong></p>                                        
{{/if}}
```

Is anything like this possible? If not can anyone offer an alternative?
Thanks